# How to get graphical output from python function when converting to exe file using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, pyinstaller, exe

I have an Anaconda environment (which has a bunch of libraries/modules installed). I have some code in this Anaconda environment (`mycode.py`).

```
import math
import statistics
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import kurtosis, skew
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def MySummary(fileIn, MyMethod):
    DF = pd.read_csv(fileIn)
    temp = DF['Vals']
    
    if (MyMethod == "mean"):
        print("The mean is " + str(statistics.mean(temp)))
    elif (MyMethod == "sd"):
        print("The standard deviation is " + str(temp.std()))
    elif (MyMethod == "Kurtosis"):
        print("The kurtosis is " + str(kurtosis(temp)))
    else:
        print("The method is not valid")

    plotIt(temp)


def plotIt(col):
    col.plot(kind = 'line', title = 'Line plot of column')
```

As you can see, there are 2 kinds of output--the graphical output (from the line plot) and the output from the `print` function.

I have a `main.py` file (same directory as `mycode.py`) for giving the `MySummary` function its arguments from the terminal/command prompt.

```
import argparse
import mycode

...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Calculate stats: mean, sd, Kurtosis")
    parser.add_argument('fileIn', help="input .csv file")
    parser.add_argument('MyMethod', help="stats method")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    mycode.MySummary(args.fileIn, args.MyMethod)
```

I have `pyinstaller` already installed in my Anaconda environment. I want to convert `main.py` to an exe file (so, `pyinstaller --onefile main.py` while inside the anaconda environment in the appropriate directory).

My questions are:

1. Will all of the modules I installed in my Anaconda environment (pandas, numpy, openpyxl, etc.) automatically port over to the generated exe file?
2. Would my output from the `print` function and the line graph still be visible to the user when they run the exe file?
3. Am I missing any other lines of code to make the exe file work properly?